# Issue with animate : First click doesn't react the same way then other clicks

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to display some content by clicking on links, and i want to have a fading animation. The problem is that with the first click, the animation is a little bit different than the other clics.

You can see a demo here : http://plnkr.co/edit/aMOW2L4tba6EfqXgW9P1?p=preview

Here is my jQuery code :

```
 $(".technoButton").click(function(event){

         $(".tab-head-content-techno").each(function( ){
                 $(this).animate({ opacity: 0 }, "fast");
                 $(this).removeClass("current");
         });

         $("."+$(this).attr("rel")).animate({ opacity: 1 }, "fast");
         $("."+$(this).attr("rel")).addClass("current");
         event.preventDefault();
     });
```

As you can see, the normal animation is : old content is hidden, then the new content is shown. With the first click : old content is hidden, new content is shown, new content is hidden and new content is shown
Can someone help ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify on how it's different? The animations all look the same to me

Comment: The normal animation is : old content is hidden, then the new content is shown. With the first click : old content is hidden, new content is shown, new content is hidden and new content is shown ..

Comment: You have to stop the plunker and play to see the difference for the first clic